# Don't show file path when playing video using VLCJ

Tags: java, video, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I'm using VLC and VLCJ to play video and audio files in my Java application, which works fine.

But there appears a text when playing the video; this text is the path of the played video.

I don't want it to appear when playing a video, so how do I disable this using Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the option `:no-video-title-show` to disable media title on video. See http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

Example using VLCJ 1.2.0:

```
                    String[] options = {
                            ":sharpen-sigma=2.0", 
                            ":blur-factor=127", 
                            ":ipv4-timeout=3000", 
                            ":no-video-title-show", 
                            ":loop", 
                            ":file-caching="+getFileCaching(),
                            ":sout-all",
                            ":sout-keep"
                    };

                    gc.getMediaPlayer().setRepeat(true);
                    gc.getMediaPlayer().setPlaySubItems(true);
                    gc.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(media, options);
```

**Update:**

Recent libVLC 2.0.x changes to `vout` feature may cause `no-video-title-show` not to work on per-playitem configuration `:no-video-title-show` anymore and may need to be set as per-global configuration `--no-video-title-show`. Pass per-global configuration options in the VLCJ factory constructor `MediaPlayerFactory(options)` instead of mediaplayer's xxxMedia method.

Answer (score 0):

libVLC 2.1 has new native API to do this - from libvlc_media_player.h:

```
LIBVLC_API 
void libvlc_media_player_set_video_title_display( libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi, libvlc_position_t position, unsigned int timeout );
```

This is available in vlcj 2.4.1 - from MediaPlayer.java:

```
void setVideoTitleDisplay(libvlc_position_e position, int timeout);
```

This API should always be used in preference to using the unsupported "options" array.

Example:

```
mediaPlayer.setVideoTitleDisplay(libvlc_position_e.disable, 0);
```